# How to watch global variables( from module which was used in main program) using debugger?

Tags: fortran, codeblocks, gfortran

I am very new in using Code::Blocks 17.12 for a creating and debugging projects.
At some stage of coding i need to watch values of local and global variables because i want to avoid any wrong logic in my fortran code.
All global variables are declared in module which was included in main program by `use, non_intrinsic`.
When I try to watch values of mentioned global variables in the watch windows got only empty space for functions and local variables.

This is my example code:

```
MODULE EES_DM_PRO

IMLICIT NONE

INTEGER :: VAR_01, VAR_02

CONTAINS 

SUBROUTINE DM_LOAD_VALUES()

  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: UN = 15 

  OPEN( UN, FILE = 'DATA.TXT')

    READ( UN, * ) VAR_01 
    READ( UN, * ) VAR_02 

  CLOSE( UN )

END SUBROUTINE DM_LOAD_VALUES

END MODULE

PROGRAM EES_DM_TS

USE, NON_INTRINSIC :: EES_DM_PRO

IMPLICIT NONE

CALL DM_LOAD_VALUES()

END PROGRAM
```

If I put a breakpoints afther line where was called subroutine and if I start debugging process in the watch window I got a empty space for locals.
Is it possible o track values of `VAR_01` and `VAR_02` in main program?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour], read [ask] and use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. How exactly are you trying to watch? Which exact comands are you using?

Comment: In `Code::Blocks` there is a debugger toolbar. Under debugging windows there is a watches window. If I put a breakpoint afther `CALL DM_LOAD_VALUES()` and if I start debugger I will not get values of variables `VAR_01` and `VAR_02`.